# Localize currency values in WPF GridView with different cultures for each row based on XAML bindings to culture name property

Tags: wpf, gridview, binding, culture

First time poster here but have been reading SO for ages and finally have run into a question that I've not been able to answer.

I've got a ListView hosting a GridView with multiple columns.  One displays a price and another displays a currency code (CAD, USD, GBP, etc).  This is all pulled out of SQL server using Entity Framework so the GridView is databound to a IEnumerable which stores the result of my query. The currency code is stored in a separate table with a localization string (en-US, en-GB) which (in a WinForms version of this app) was previously used in String.Format() to localize the currency to display the appropriate currency format and symbol.

The problem I have is in XAML binding the ConverterCulture of the Price binding to the Currency.LocalizedCultureName to get it to format correctly.  Here's my current XAML:

```
            <ListView Grid.Column="0" Name="pricingListingListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource pricesByYear}}">
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <GroupBox Header="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                                        </GroupBox>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource leftAlignedColumnHeader}" Header="Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Source.Date}" Width="60" />
                    <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource leftAlignedColumnHeader}" Header="Price" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price, StringFormat='{}{0:C}', ConverterCulture={Binding Currency.LocalizedCultureName}}" Width="60" />
                    <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource leftAlignedColumnHeader}" Header="Currency" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Currency.Code}" Width="60" />
                    <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource leftAlignedColumnHeader}" Header="Unit" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Unit.Name}" Width="60" />
                    <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource leftAlignedColumnHeader}" Header="Source" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Source.Name}" Width="125" />
                    <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource leftAlignedColumnHeader}" Header="Project" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Project.Description}" Width="125" />
                    <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource leftAlignedColumnHeader}" Header="Plant Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Project.Plant.Name}" Width="100" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

PricesByYear is simply a CollectionViewSource which pulls the IEnumerable out of a DP in my code behind.  The data is pulled out correctly, just not formatted.

This compiles fine, but generates a XamlParseException when I load the window containing it: *A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'ConverterCulture' property of type 'Binding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.*

The line generating the error is: *<GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource leftAlignedColumnHeader}" Header="Price" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price, StringFormat='{}{0:C}', ConverterCulture={Binding Currency.LocalizedCultureName}}" Width="60" />*

The short-form objective is to display the price, but format it according to the culture name stored as a string value. Each row in the gridview could potentially be different. As it seems I cannot bind within a binding, is there an alternative way I could go about this?

### Answer

Multibinding did the trick, here's the working XAML:

```
<local:LocalizeCurrencyMultiConverter x:Key="localizeCurrencyMultiConverter"/>
```

...

```
<GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource leftAlignedColumnHeader}" Header="Price"  Width="60">
                        <!--DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price, StringFormat='{}{0:C}', ConverterCulture={Binding Currency.LocalizedCultureName}}"-->
                        <GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource localizeCurrencyMultiConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="Price"/>
                                <Binding Path="Currency.LocalizedCultureName"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                    </GridViewColumn>
```

And the converter class:

```
    public class LocalizeCurrencyMultiConverter :System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        string localizedCurrency;

        if (!values.Any() || values[0] == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Convert requires a minimum a price to display, and optionally a culture.");

        double originalCurrency;
        if (!double.TryParse(values[0].ToString(), out originalCurrency))
            return values[0];
        string localization = (values[1] ?? "en-CA").ToString();

        try {
            localizedCurrency = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(localization), "{0:c}", originalCurrency);
        } catch {
            localizedCurrency = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-CA"), "{0:c}", originalCurrency);
        }
        return localizedCurrency;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a MultiBinding with a binding to the Price property and a binding the Culture property,
2. Write a MultiValueConverter and use the values to output the string you want.

I am going to make it easy for you:

[MSDN MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx)

[MSDN MultiConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Grafix - that worked. I'll post the working code in the OP.